# How to fix my search code connecting to Access in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, listview, ms-access, listviewitem

Something's wrong with the "search" code connecting with Access database. I'm using Visual Basic. It's very hard, I need it for Defends.

[image]

```
Private Sub btn_search_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
    Dim connstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=C:\Users\Leonel EJ Jet JM\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DatabaseLeJM\DatabaseLEJm.accdb"
    Dim sqlcmd As String = "SELECT fld_stud_id, fld_fullname, fld_address, fld_birthday, fld_school from tbl_studentdata WHERE fld_stud_id = '" & txt_bsearch.Text & "'"
    Dim sql As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlcmd)
    sql.Connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connstring)
    sql.Connection.Open()
    sql.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim DA As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql)
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    DA.Fill(DS, "logictable")
    If DS.Tables("logictable").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim itemcollection(100) As String
        For r = 0 To DS.Tables("logictable").Rows.Count - 1
            For c = 0 To DS.Tables("logictable").Columns.Count - 1
                itemcollection(c) = DS.Tables("logictable").Rows(r)(c).ToString
            Next
            Dim LVI As New ListViewItem(itemcollection)
            lv_data.Items.Add(LVI)
        Next
    End If
    sql.Connection.Close()


End Sub
```

Comment: Would you edit this question to: (a) remove the image and replace it with the text of what you want to show, e.g. the text of the error message, and (b) explain what Defends is? Also please (c) explain where you think the error might be, and (d) in what way it can be seen? We don't know what your code is meant to do, presently.

Comment: (I've improved the text a little bit to add paragraphing, to remove the all-caps shouting and demands for urgency, and have downvoted to remind you of this for your next question).

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear: You miss a value for `txt_stud_id.Text`.

So debug your code to make sure this textbox has a value before you proceed.